# Falha ao estabelecer conexão entre dois containers Docker

Tags: docker

Eu tenho uma aplicação que está dividida em 2 partes: Frontend e Backend. O Frontend é uma aplicação React JS e o backend é uma aplicação Java. Esse projeto está rodando no Docker, onde possuo 3 containers: **frontend**, **backend** e **db** (database). Meu problema é que não consigo fazer o frontend enviar uma requisição para o container do backend. Abaixo estão os arquivos de configuração do Docker:

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Dockerfile frontend:

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM node:8.12.0 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

RUN yarn

COPY ./ /app/

RUN yarn run build

# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx

RUN  rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build-stage  /app/build/  /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Dockerfile backend:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD /build/libs/reurb-sj-13-11-19.jar reurb-sj-13-11-19.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "reurb-sj-13-11-19.jar", "--app.db.host=db"]
```

No **Frontend** eu já tentei mandar requisição para:

- localhost:8085
- 172.18.0.3:8085
- 172.18.0.3
- 0.0.0.0:8085

Quando tento mandar a requisição do Frontend, ela fica "ativa" por uns 10 segundos e depois retorna com erro. O estranho é que a requisição não retorna nenhum *status*.

OBS.: Eu já varri a internet e todo mundo fala para colocar o EXPOSE, PORTS e o LINKS (lá no docker-compose), mas ainda assim nada funciona.

Comment: ela fica ativa por uns 10 segundos e depois retorna com erro. Qual é o erro retornado? Você verificou se sua aplicação de back-end realmente está servindo requisições na porta exposta?

Comment: Opa, o erro é um "err_connection_reset". E sim, o backend está ouvindo as requisições na porta 8085. Lembrando que este erro eu só consigo ver no console, pois na aba Network do Chrome, a requisição lá não ilustra qualquer status da ação.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você sobe containers no Docker, eles funcionam como servidores isolados, então não vai ser possível mesmo você utilizar `localhost` ou qualquer outra variação de um container para outro. Imagine que você está em outro servidor, `localhost` vai apontar para a própria maquina que você está executando, não para o outro servidor.

Porém quando você utiliza o Docker Compose, é criado uma network do tipo bridge para sua aplicação que é capaz de resolver a conexão de rede através do nome no service no seu docker-compose.yml.

Então, para o frontend acessar seu backend, use o endereço `backend:8085`.

Observação: remova configurações como `container_name`, `exposes` e `links` do seu docker-compose.yml. Algumas delas são superluas e até descontinuadas (no caso do `links`). Só use se realmente precisar:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8085:8085"
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```